# How to have incremented variable in global substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, increment

```
$html =~ s[<p>(.+?)</p>][<li value="++$count">$1</li>]gis;
```

How can I achieve the above code in perl?

I need the `++$count` to be a number that increments for every substitution that takes place.

Comment: `$html =~ s[<p>(.+?)</p>]['<li value="'.++$count.'">'.$1.'</li>']esgi;`

Answer (score 6):

Use [baby cart](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby_cart) `@{[ ]}` from perlsecret

```
$html =~ s[<p>(.+?)</p>][<li value="@{[++$count]}">$1</li>]gis;
```

From [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)

> > The way it works is that when the @{...} is seen in the double-quoted string, it's evaluated as a block. The block creates a reference to an anonymous array containing the results of eval.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done?  Is it creating an array or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/e` modifier to turn the substitution part of the `s///` into a Perl expression that is evaluated once per substitution.

```
$html =~ s[<p>(.+?)</p>]['<li value="'.++$count.qq{">$1</li>}]gise;
```

Because it's a full expression, you need to put the rest of your string into quotes. I've used single and double quotes for the part without and with interpolation respectively.

```
my $html = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";
my $count = 0;
$html =~ s[<p>(.+?)</p>]['<li value="'.++$count.qq{">$1</li>}]gise;

print $html;

__END__
<li value="1">foo</li><li value="2">bar</li>
```